# $http get angularjs unable to pass param?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

```
var myFunc = function(url){

        console.log(url);

          $http({
              url: "http://example.me/",
              method: "GET",
              data:{url:url},
          }).finally(function () {
})
```

Not sure why when I echo in my PHP $_GET['url'] I didn't get anything, is there anything wrong with the snytax above? btw I didn't get any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use "**params**", not "data", **data** is for POST or PUT method

```
$http({
   url: "http://example.me/",
   method: "GET",
   params:{url:url},
}).finally(function () {
```

Comment: what a careles mistake! but my echo $_GET['url'] display nothing, any idea?

Comment: check in developer tools (F12 in chrome and FF) / network, if there is your request and what URL is it calling, is that url http://example.me/?url=SOMESTRING ?? or it is without params? Also try to disable cache to be sure you are using new version of your script, and add "     cache: false" to yout $http params: `$http({
   url: "http://example.me/",
   method: "GET",
   params:{url:url},
   cache: false
})`